# Refactor JFoenix JFXDialogLayout alert notification code to a simpler form so that it can be reused for other classes

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

how can I refactor the following code so that only the code in `deleteButton.setOnAction(deleteEvent -> {//only this code varies}` changes. Everything else will stay the same but the block of code in the lambda expression varies from time to time when I call the class from another class. The block of code that goes through the lambda expression is supposed to be a void method.

```
public class A {    

    public void test() {
        // ensure that user can't close the alert
        Stage primaryStage = (Stage) RootLayoutController.getRootLayout().getScene().getWindow();
        JFXAlert<javafx.scene.control.ButtonType> alert = new JFXAlert<>(primaryStage);
        alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        alert.setOverlayClose(false);

        //create font awesome icon
        String ICON = "\uf071";
        Label labelIcon = new Label(ICON); 
        labelIcon.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'FontAwesome'; -fx-font-size: 60px; -fx-text-fill: #D34336;");
        labelIcon.setPadding(new Insets(0,5,0,0));

        // Create the content of the JFXAlert with JFXDialogLayout
        JFXDialogLayout layout = new JFXDialogLayout();
        Label labelHeading = new Label("Alert Notification");
        Label labelBody = new Label("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
        layout.setHeading(labelHeading);
        layout.setBody(new VBox(new HBox(labelIcon, labelBody)));

        // Buttons get added into the actions section of the layout.
        JFXButton deleteButton = new JFXButton("Delete");
        deleteButton.setDefaultButton(true);
        deleteButton.setOnAction(deleteEvent -> {
            //only this block of code changes

            alert.hideWithAnimation();
        });

        JFXButton cancelButton = new JFXButton("Cancel");
        cancelButton.setCancelButton(true);
        cancelButton.setOnAction(closeEvent -> alert.hideWithAnimation());

        layout.setActions(deleteButton, cancelButton);
        alert.setContent(layout); 
        alert.showAndWait();      
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just have the `onAction` call another method? `deleteButton.setOnAction(deleteEvent -> doSomething());` Then you can pass in any necessary parameters that control was the method does.

Comment: Simply pass the `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` to the method as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear from your question what you are trying to accomplish, but I will take a wild stab at it.

If you are looking to be able to pass a code block to the `deleteButton.setOnAction()` method, you could use an `Interface` and pass implementations of that interface to the `A` class. Then just pass that reference to an internal method for the `onAction` lambda.

Here is a very quick example of how you could do something like this:

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Action button
        Button btnDoSomething = new Button("Do something...");
        btnDoSomething.setOnAction(e -> doTheThings(new ImplDoSomething()));

        Button btnDoSomethingElse = new Button("Do something else...");
        btnDoSomethingElse.setOnAction(e -> doTheThings(new ImplDoSomethingElse()));

        VBox mainPane = new VBox(5);
        mainPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        mainPane.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(btnDoSomething, btnDoSomethingElse);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));

        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private void doTheThings(IParameterMethod parameterMethod) {

        parameterMethod.call();

    }
}
```

**The IParameterMethod.java Interface:**

```
public interface IParameterMethod {

    void call();

}
```

Then you can create as many classes as you like that implement that interface, each with their own `call()` method, allowing you to execute different code.

**ImplDoSomething.java**

```
public class ImplDoSomething implements IParameterMethod {

    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Doing something!");
    }
}
```

**ImplDoSomethingElse.java:**

```
public class ImplDoSomethingElse implements IParameterMethod {

    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Doing something else!");
    }
}
```

This should be easily adapted for your project.

Comment: An new interface... Because apparently `Runnable` is not good enough...